# How to register store as global variable object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, store, vue-reactivity

Currently I'm using a reactive `store.js` like so:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const re = reactive({})

export default {
    re
}
```

which then can be used in components like so:

```
<script setup>
import store from "../../../scripts/store";

store.re.hello = 'hello world'
</script>
```

Is there a way to register the `store.re` object in vue, so that:

1. it becomes globally available in all components without import and
2. `re` from `store.re` gets omitted to just `store`, when calling it? I find it unnecessary boilerplate

Comment: You could transform your store into a plugin https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using the composition api, you could make use of [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#provide)

You would be then be able to write something like:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";
const re = reactive({})
provide('re', re)
```

and then resolve it from your components:

```
import { inject } from 'vue'
const count = inject('re')
```

In this way, you'll be also able to mock this dependency if you're going to test your component.

Comment: Does this not increase boilerplate by one line? Maybe I'm just not getting it.